# Вызов нужного метода из аргумента

Tags: python, ооп

Есть класс AA, наследник класса A, имеющий метод X. И есть совсем другой класс, в котором есть возможность вызывать метод X у объектов, переданных ему. Вот при попытке вызвать метод и происходит ошибка.

```
class A
   ...
   def X():
      pass

class AA(A)
   ...
   def X():
      ...

class Executor
   def CallX(*args)
      for a in args:
         a.X()

exec = Executor()
exec.CallX( AA() ) # ошибка "Executror не содержит метод X"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class A:
    def X(self):
        pass

class AA(A):
    def X(self):
        pass

class Executor:
    def CallX(self, *args):
        #     ^^^^   <---- NOTE!!!
        for a in args:
            a.X()
```